# Whenever I zoom in, zoom out, or stretch out my browser, every positioning gets screwed up

Tags: html, css

I know this might be a ridiculous question but please bear with me. I am still a CSS noob.

So I started building my personal website with HTML/CSS but for some reason, whenever I preview it and then zoom in, zoom out, or stretch out the browser even a little bit, all the positioning will move around and get screwed up. It won't stay in that same exact position as how it's shown when I first open it in my browser.

Very frustrating and I don't know what the issue is. What do I have to do to resolve this issue? Please help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jason H Kang</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </div>
         <div id="footer">
         </div>
    </div>

    <div id="span">
        <h1>Jason Kang</h1>
        <p class="basicinfo">23 Years Old | Junior Web Developer | NJ</p>
        <p class="introduction">Hello I am Jason Kang. Welcome to my personal website! Please contact me if you have further enquiries :)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="image">
        <img src="kangjason.jpg" alt="Face"> 
    </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS file ...

```
body {
    background-color: #4A708B;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5% 0.5% 0.5% 0.5%;
    background-color: #3CB371;
}

#header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#header ul li {
    float: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 14%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.313em 2.813em;
    font-family: Gill Sans;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 1.250px;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: relative;
}

#header ul li:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 1.7em;
}

#header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    padding-left: 16.5em;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
}

.basicinfo {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 12.8em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.introduction {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20em;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

#footer {
    background:#000000;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 205px;
    height: 205px;
    padding: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the joys of responsive web design. Your best bet, especially as a beginner, is to use some kind of framework that provides the ability to design for different browser sizes without you having to deal with it such as [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com).

Comment: Also, in formatting your code, your HTML is invalid. You are missing a closing `<ul>` tag in your header and you also have a footer `<div>` above the rest of your content?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally when we work on a responsive website, we should have a container/wrapper div which would wrap all the inner elements. In your case, the div with id "span" is not inside the wrapper.

Also, it would be suggested to use a responsive framework like bootstrap or foundation or skeleton for better understanding

Comment: but if I use a framework, wouldn't it replace all my colors and the style i want with others?

Comment: no .. it wont. you can apply your own css by giving them a class name and adding that class to the bootstrap default class

Comment: you can always use your own classes for color.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is responsive design, and making a responsive website without the help of any framework is quite hard for a beginner. I would suggest you to use a frame work such as [Bootsrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation by Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

You can use these frameworks and modify them as per your needs.